# getting the value of two fields with checkbox

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I'm trying to get two values based on a checkbox in a continuous form.

[image]

Whenever I click a checkbox I want to get the adjacent values of    **Cost of Item * Quantity.** I'm new to VBA, so I have no idea where to begin.

## EDIT

I figured it out for the most part, but I'm having issues with summing multiple values I get from the check boxes.

```
Private Sub Check8_Click()
 If (Me.[isChecked] = True) Then
  Me.[Text21] = [TotalRolledCost] * [ORDER_QTY]
 End If

 If (Me.[isChecked] = False) Then
  Me.[Text21] = ""
 End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Me.[TotalRolledCost]*Me.[Order_QTY] ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used an unbound textbox to sum the values.

```
=SUM([TotalRolledCost] * [ORDER_QTY])
```